# Python debugging in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed the new VScode v1.29.1 with Python 2018.11.0 extension and cannot execute the debugger. I was able to debug Python in previous VScode installs, but now I am getting the error: "Program 'python' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation". The status bar at the bottom indicates I am running Python 3.6.4 and my launch.json is configured for Python: current File (Integrated Terminal).

Why is this so complicated? Visual Studio, Spyder, Pycharm etc. you just install and start working, but VScode requires all this configuration to perform even the simplest debugging?

Comment: execute `path/to/python.exe ${file}` not just `${file}`

Comment: Does anything happen when you press F5 ?

Comment: I added:"pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}" to the launch.json. Now python debugger loads, but the "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "\\path\\to\\custom\\libs}, is not working and am I am getting module not found errors.

Comment: Yes, why is this complicated?